# using php curl for valid http URL is returning 500 server error

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to get the response text of a link shortener. When I echo the exact HTTP url and put it into a browser, it works fine and returns a text string (and nothing else). When I run curl using the code below, I consistently get a blank result and when I check the http code, I get a 500 error. The code on the site where this is running doesn't come back 500, so it must be the shortener (EDIT: which is our own, running a modified version of yourls), but I'm not getting anything wrong when I run the same url in the browser... I have checked the error logs on both the link shortener URL and the website this code is on and there is no error code. I'm out of ideas. I have spent since the early morning hours on this and can't see a reason why it'd do this... ANY ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$urlToShorten="thisurl.com";
$buildURL = "http://bigironicallynamedlittlelinkshortener.com/url-api.php?action=shorturl&url=".urlencode($urlToShorten)."&format=json";
$cr = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_URL, $buildURL);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($cr);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($cr, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "Return code: ".$httpCode;
curl_close( $cr );

echo "<br>Result: ".$result;
```

Comment: Use Firebug's Net tab in FF or somethign like HTTPFox to see what's being sent by the browser - possibly the shortener's expecting a cookie which curl isn't sending by default.

Comment: This is going to be incredibly difficult to troubleshot without knowing that the real "bigironicallynamedlittlelinkshortener.com" is.  I found that "x90.es" has an identical syntax (url-api.php?action=shorturl&url=) and it seems to be working properly. Would you mind sharing what the shortener's URL is?

Comment: Is this allowed under the shortener's TOS? Could be a user-agent or similar check preventing automated access

Comment: It's our own internal shortener which is, basically, running the yourls engine. On the shortener's side, it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user agent, here is how it will look in CLI.

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" http://example.com
```